# Can I simplify this fit line (e^-log(x))?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting

I noticed a relationship in my data and was able to get a line to fit reasonably well with nls in R (residual sum-of-squares = 9.652) with the function:
y = a * e^(log10(x) * b)
a = 120.1 and b - -2.5

I'm super rusty at stats, but it seems like there ought to be something simpler than e^-log10(x) that describes a quick decay followed by a slower decay. Any ideas?

[image: proportion vs. log10(length) graph]

Comment: "Quick decay followed by slower decay" is *more* complex than "simple exponential decay," which is the model you already have. Could you please clarify your meaning?

Comment: I didn't call it a "simple exponential decay" intentionally (having Googled that earlier to find a similar shape to no avail), so I'm not sure why you thought that's what I said. I was just wondering if there was another function that has a similar shape that would fit similarly well. If there's not, so be it. But e^-log10(x) has no biological significance so I'm not attached to it if there's something similar.

Comment: Regardless of what you might state in English, your formula is equivalent to $y=ax^\beta$ where $\beta = b/\log(10):$ that is, it's a power law.  "Something similar" is too vague.  You need to explain more clearly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, as I discovered below with Lys's help. I was looking for an equivalent formula that was simpler (i.e. the power law) or another that might have a similarly good fit for the graph shown. Thank you for also providing the former. I do have one remaining question, though, which base log would it be in the beta? It should be e, right, given my initial function?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the exponential decay formula $y = a\cdot e^{kx}$ without the `log10` and see if it gives you a better fit. The exponential decay is also easily interpretable.

You might want to check [this reference](https://robotenique.github.io/posts/nonlinear-models/) for some non linear equations, and see if any of them would be better for you case (it's in Python, but the important  things are the formulas)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the reference! The exponential decay formula didn't work (it throws and infinity apparently), but that's a super helpful reference site and the "Power Regression" Y = a * X^b seems to have been what I was after (using that as the base function arrives at an identical residual sum-of-squares). Much appreciated!